# Meta Box Plugin Cloned Fields - Multiple Foreach values

Tags: custom-field, metabox, customization, php

I have the following code that I can't get working. I have two cloneable fields that are being output as one entity (URL and thumbnail image). These are cloned fields using the Meta Box Plugin by Deluxe Blogging, so I need to be able to do an if statement if there is nothing at all and then I need to be able to repeat the thumbnail and URL twice (if there are two separate entries).

```
<?php if 
$videoID = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_danieltiger_repvid', true );
$videoThmb = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_danieltiger_repthmb', true );
    foreach ( $videoID as $value )
        {
            echo '<div class="video-pops">';
            echo '<a class="thumb video-pop-lb" data-video-pid="';
            echo $videoID;
            echo '">';
            echo '<span></span>';
            echo '<img width="157" height="88" alt="<?php the_title(); ?> image" src="';
            echo $videoThmb;
            echo '" /></a>';
            echo '</div>';
        } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

The example code from Deluxe Blogging on outputting cloned fields is the following:

```
$metas = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta_key', true );
    foreach ( $metas as $meta )
     {
         echo $meta;
     }
```

I can't seem to figure out how to work in the two separate values. I have another field I'm cloning and outputting in my theme correctly but I just can't get the gist on this one.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amit helped you out, but while we're at it you really shouldn't be echoing everything like that. Should probably try this instead:

```
<?php
foreach ( $videoID as $value ) { ?>
    <div class="video-pops">
        <a class="thumb video-pop-lb" data-video-pid="<?php echo $videoID; ?>"></a>
<?php } ?>
```

And so on.

You may even be better off using the alternate syntax;

```
foreach ( $videoID as $value ) :
...
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm just doing it as I know how, so any tricks to help do it better are appreciated.

Comment: Hey we all start somewhere, right? I did the same thing when I first started off, but you'll grow to love the alternate syntax, it's much clearer (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Set the last paramter as `false` to return multiple values for same custom field. Read more about [parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta#Parameters) you can use for this function.

```
$metas = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta_key', false );
    foreach ( $metas as $meta )
     {
         echo $meta;
     }
```